# How to use disable-output-escaping with identity transform on xslt

Tags: java, xslt

I'm trying to apply a transform with java (`currentXSLT.transform(xmlFile, outputFile);`) But I'm getting escaped text. I need the characters that are being scaped, from the text of the XML.

So far I have tried with this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by not work? d-o-e (which is almost always a bad idea) only changes the output of < and & so you should get an identity transform except converting the well formed input <foo>&lt;</foo>not the not well formed result <foo><</foo>  is that _really_ what you want?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi, I know it is not a good idea, but there are some other characters that need to be escaped, for example:
`<lastName>Johnson &amp; Johnson</lastName>` should give `<lastName>Johnson & Johnson</lastName>` which is going to be inserted into a database that has already Johnson & Johnson to compare.

Comment: as I say d-o-e _only_ affects & and < (if you are outputting in utf8) but if you just want a string output don't use the xml output method and if you do want xml output why force `<lastName>Johnson & Johnson</lastName>` which is not well formed so will just be a fatal error when read by any XML system? If you database has the string "Johnson & Johnson" then to put that string in XML you need Johnson &amp; Johnson

Comment: The thing is: It is already being checked before. It is a part of a xml, and the part that is being tranformed has several other special characters like &#130; but, it is part of a well formed xml, the 1st parameter is a StringBuffer. So, the only workaround would be changing a BufferedWriter to String to hold it, unescape it and then write it, because I can't change the script for the DB. See my dilemma? Either the question or the one I mentioned.
And the source if from an external source that we can't change either.

Comment: When I say well formed, is that it has been verified that the content is between tags.

Comment: That isnt what well formed means though. <lastName>Johnson & Johnson</lastName> the content is "between tags" but it is not well formed and it's a fatal error to give that to an XML system. surely you either want to store the string "Johnson & Johnson" or the xml fragment "<lastName>Johnson &amp; Johnson</lastName>" storing something that is a syntax error seems.... strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I couldn't do it with plain xslt, I had to use apache commons in order to unescape the text. Since it *was a business requirement* to keep the invalid signs, I had to find a workaround:

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(xmlFile, new StreamResult(stringWriter));
String xmlOutput = stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
xmlOutput = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(xmlOutput);
```